# Angularjs $scope.data not showing in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I get the response from POST, it prints the data in the console but it doesn't show the data in the html page.

I have my controller, its just that the {{user}}  doesnt show in html page

I can see the what it returns in the console,

```
    angular.module('app.AllUsersCtrl', [])
    .controller('AllUsersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $window, $state) {
        $scope.getAccount = function (n) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/FYPapp/getAccount',
                data: $.param({
                    username: n
                }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.user = JSON.stringify(data);
            });

        };
    });
```

**Data Returns **

```
scripts.js:95 {"id":118,"firstname":"Lauren","lastname":"Smithss","description":"the Makup Chair the.....","enabled":true,"user":{"userid":21,"username":"theMak","email":"theMak22@mail.com","password":"995bf49114defd4f35d10e477135b89112ecdc2f25af6ab7969112842919ba4dc193b194f9485671","enabled":true},"followers":[],"username":"theMak"}
```

**HTML: This is the html page**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/app/css/css.scss">
<div class="mainDiv">

<h1> Profile Details</h1>
    {{user}}

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your html and data as well?

Comment: It will be better if you define your data before the http call like this: `$scope.data = {}` and then make the call.

Comment: what is your controller name ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee that is unnecessary

Comment: i think like {{ user.id }}

Comment: Why are you stringifying the data? Just try `$scope.user = data`. You can display it for debugging via `<pre>{{user | json}}</pre>`

Comment: Also, the `success` method has been removed in Angular 1.6 (deprecated in earlier versions). You should be using `$http(...).then(response => $scope.user = response.data)`

Comment: Is the HTML template shown in the controller's scope? ie, is it contained within an HTML element with `ng-controller` or otherwise bound by a `templateUrl` definition?

Comment: Its bound by templateUrl to the html page in the main app.js

Comment: I have changed the   $scope.data = JSON.stringify(data);  to  $scope.user = data;  but still the html page doesn't show the data

Comment: @JJ9999 bound how? In a directive, component, route, state, etc? Also, what executes the `getAccount` method in your controller? There's not enough information here to answer your question

Comment: its bound by state : .state('profile', {
      url: "/profile",
         templateUrl: '/views/profile.html',
         controller: 'AllUsersCtrl',
         controllerAs: 'allusers'
       })

Comment: the getAccount is when a users click on an image

Comment: Question as it stands should not be getting upvotes, it has no code or explanation of any merit.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper I've reverted the question to the previous version. Not sure what OP was thinking removing all the code :/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you need to define our controller with `ng-controller` and also the `ng-app` which will be your module name.

Then you will need to make the data call.

After that you can directly assign the data to scope like this:

```
$scope.user = data;
```

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption. It's obvious from OP's question that the controller is loading and *something* is calling the `getAccount` method. Whether the template shown is in the controller's scope is unanswered though

Comment: @Phil I read that later, that he is getting the data. But since he is getting the data in the JSon format there is no need to use JSon.stringify().

Answer (score 1):

As it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078313/angularjs-scope-data-not-showing-in-html/42078951#comment71329215_42078313) you're using a controller alias, ie

```
.state('profile', {
  url: "/profile",
  templateUrl: '/views/profile.html',
  controller: 'AllUsersCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'allusers' // this one here
})
```

You should be assigning methods and properties to the controller instance, eg

```
.controller('AllUsersCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
  var ctrl = this;
  this.getAccount = function(n) {
    $http(...).then(function(response) {
      ctrl.user = response.data;
    });
  };
}])
```

and in your template...

```
<img ng-click="allusers.getAccount(something)"...
```

and

```
<h1>Profile Details</h1>

<!-- for debugging -->
<pre>{{allusers.user | json}}</pre>

<!-- or for prod -->
<p>{{allusers.user.firstname}} {{allusers.user.lastname}}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing ng-controller in your html templates.

```
<h1> Profile Details</h1>
{{user}}
```